# How to cleanup this useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I am trying to fetch the user information from an authenticated AWS Cognito User Pool using the AWS Amplify libraries in react.

The following code gives me the following console error message after I logout from the app:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:211:82

Unfortunately I am not a front-end specialist and the react-hooks documentation are going over my head.

My first attempt was to create 2 separate useEffect blocks but it complained that `user` was not defined. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
import React from "react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import {
  AmplifyAuthenticator,
  AmplifySignOut,
  withAuthenticator,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from "@aws-amplify/ui-components";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: "...",
    userPoolId: "...",
    userPoolWebClientId: "...",
  },
});

const App = () => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();
  const [userGroup, setUserGroup] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
      setAuthState(nextAuthState);
      setUser(authData);
      if (authData !== undefined) {
        setUserGroup(authData.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]);
      }
      console.log("user data: ", authData);
    });

  }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
    <div>
      <AmplifySignOut />
      <div>Hello {user.username} from {userGroup}</div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator />
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Comment: Probably the `onAuthUIStateChange` call before component is mounted, so in the callback `setUserGroup, setAuthState,  setUser` cause to throw the error on console. What is `onAuthUIStateCHange` does ? Is it call when `AuthState` from the node package change ?

Comment: This is as much documentation as I could find about this callback. https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#authstate

Comment: Can you try it without the `return ()` ?

Comment: You are not listening to an event you just used a method that fire when authState change. So there is nothing to clear from useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is trying to update the state after component unmount.
The onAuthUIStateChange function seems to have been designed with the subscribe-unsubscribe architecture.
It returns the unsubscribe function of this function itself.
source code: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/amplify-ui-components/src/common/helpers.ts#L58,L82

you can use it:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
    setAuthState(nextAuthState);
    setUser(authData);
    if (authData !== undefined) {
      setUserGroup(authData.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]);
    }
    console.log("user data: ", authData);
  });

 return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import {
  AmplifyAuthenticator,
  AmplifySignOut,
  withAuthenticator,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from "@aws-amplify/ui-components";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: "...",
    userPoolId: "...",
    userPoolWebClientId: "...",
  },
});

const App = () => {
  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false); 
  const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();
  const [userGroup, setUserGroup] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDidMount(true);
    onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
      setAuthState(nextAuthState);
      setUser(authData);
      if (authData !== undefined) {
        setUserGroup(authData.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]);
      }
      console.log("user data: ", authData);
    });
   return () => setDidMount(false);
  }, []);

   if(!didMount) {
   return null;
   }

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
    <div>
      <AmplifySignOut />
      <div>Hello {user.username} from {userGroup}</div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator />
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Comment: your answer does not solve this problem. Because the problem stems from calling callback after unmount.